# How to solve : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error?

Tags: oracle

I have a long text in CLOB and I'm trying to use the function **htp.prn**

Here is my code :

```
n := dbms_lob.getlength(html);      -- n is 31745 characters

if n<32000 then
    htp.prn(HTML);                  -- << Error raised here 
else
    do something else
end if;
```

When using the function **htp.prn**, I'm getting the error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

I know he text size allowed is 32672 characters. And the text contains some Chinese characters. So, I assume the problem is coming from **dbms_lob.getlength**

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Unicode characters (you mentioned Chinese), and your database is using a multibyte characterset, then the number of bytes is greater than the number of characters. 32767 is a hard limit of *bytes*. Whereas, dbms_lob.getlength for CLOBs and NCLOBs counts *characters*. So you probably are over the 32K limit in bytes.

You cannot easily get the length of a CLOB in bytes. There are various unpleasant workarounds, but probably the easiest thing for you to do is simply trap the exception rather than predict it:

```
n := dbms_lob.getlength(html);

if n<32000 then
    declare
      value_error exception;
      pragma exception_init(value_error,-06502);
    begin
      htp.prn(HTML);
    exception
       when value_error then
         null;
    end;
else
    do something else
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Multibyte characters, eh?

Perhaps you could handle it by splitting that *string* into smaller chunks.

My example uses *not that long string* which is then split into 20 characters in length. I'm just displaying them (line #10); you'd `htp.prn` it (line #11).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    html   clob := 'How to solve: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error';
  3    l_var  varchar2(20);  --> you'd use e.g. 5000
  4    l_size number := 20;  --> you'd use e.g. 5000
  5    l_pos  number := 1;
  6  begin
  7    while dbms_lob.getlength(html) >= l_pos
  8    loop
  9      l_var := dbms_lob.substr(html, l_size, l_pos);
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_var);
 11      htp.prn(l_var);
 12      l_pos := l_pos + length(l_var);
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
How to solve: ORA-06
502: PL/SQL: numeric
or value error

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It's exacly what my piece of code is about. Splitting long clobs into small chunks. However I need to keep the chunk size big enough to avoid long loops which is theoretically : 32672. That's why I'm asking. Otherwise of course if we reduce the chunk size to a very small value, it will work. I was wondering if there is a "deterministic" way to handle it instead of groping.